# Making a user account dedicated to a single script in centos

Tags: linux, centos, ssh, shell, perl

I am trying to make a SSH login for someone on my box. But when they login I want it to auto load a perl script and for them ONLY  to be aloud to see / use that perl script.

I only know how to use useradd command, I do not know how to set perms ect.

I don't know how to explain this in more detail. But any help would be aswsome!!!

Answer (score 2):

Create a new user for this 'someone' and put your `perl` script in his home directory and then make an entry in his `.bash_profile` for invoking the `perl` script.

FYI : The ~/.bash_profile gets executed during every login shell (eg: ssh,switch user etc)

Example:

```
suku@ubuntu-vm:~$ cat hello.pl 
#!/usr/bin/perl
print "Hello World\n";

suku@ubuntu-vm:~$ cat .bash_profile 
perl ~/hello.pl

suku@ubuntu-vm:~$ su - suku
Password: 
Hello World
```

**[EDIT]**
`useradd -m username` will create a user with his home directory as `/home/username`

If you really want to limit this user's scope only to read and execute your perl script, you need to set immutable attribute for his home directory

Setting immutable attribute:

```
sudo chattr +i /home/username
```

Removing immutable attribute:

```
sudo chattr -i /home/username
```

If you do so, this user can't touch anything new in his home directory. But he can execute/read your perl script

Comment: Hmm, I only know how to make a account with useradd command, I don't know how to link the account to a home directory nor do what you just said lol.

Comment: I use centos version 5.

Comment: Okay, I made the .bash_profile and I cannot beleive how simple that was lol. Now how can I limit him to ONLY stay in his home directory? because with control+c you can break and go out of bounds.

Comment: Read the update in the answer

Comment: It would be better to use `exec` to call the secondary program so that the shell is replaced with the program - that way once the program exits (either naturally or by an interrupt) the SSH session will be closed.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to do this is to use the authorized_keys file. You can restrict a user to run just one command with one Key. So, if a user login with one specified key, he will be able to run just one command.

The setup is to use the command ="" directive, specified in the authorized_keys file. The syntax for this looks like:

```
command ="command",  KEY
```

This tells SSH to run command and then exit. It effectively limits your ability to run commands on the remote server.

In order to run multiple commands securely, you have a few options. First, consider calling a script instead of command. For example, run top, df -k and hostname from a shell script named `myscript.sh` and set `command="/path/to/myscript.sh"`. Second, if you need to run multiple commands at different times during the day to same host, you could create another key for your user.

For auto-loading feature, you can simply put it in .bash_profile, present in their home directory, as described by Suku.